# Import list in flask in html table

Tags: python, html, flask

I am facing an issue while accessing the contents in html file of the python list declared in Flask code. Here is the brief details.

FLASK code:

```
class TestSuiteForm(FlaskForm):
  TestCases = ['Check Red LED Status', 'Check Red2 LED Status', 'Check Red3 LED Status']
  NumOfTestCases = len(TestCases)

@app.route("/offlineTest")
def offlineTest():
  form = TestSuiteForm()
  return render_template("offlineTest.html", title='Offline Testing', form=form)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(debug=True)
```

HTML code: Adding snippet which have the issue.

```
<p >
      <h4>Test Cases2</h4>
      <table id="testcaseTable2" style="width:50%"> </table>
   </p>

   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      var text = "";

      text = "<tr> <th>Sr num </th> <th>Test Case Name </th> <th>Select/Deselect</th> </tr>"

      for (var i = 0; i < {{form.NumOfTestCases}}; i++)
      {
         text += '<tr>'
         text += '<td>' + [i+1] + '</td>'
         text += '<td>"' + {{form.TestCases[i]}} + '"</td>'        //Not working; output NaN
         text += '<td><input type="checkbox"/> &nbsp;</td> </tr>'
      }
      document.getElementById("testcaseTable2").innerHTML = text
   </script>
```

I am not able to access the {{form.TestCases[i]}} data, but if I hardcode i with 0,1,2 it gives proper data.
Please let me know the problem. I beleive it is happening due to string concatenation but not sure how to solve it. I am really new to web page design so pardon me if its a stupid mistake.

Comment: `i` isn't defined server-side during the template formatting

Comment: You need a jinja loop for this. You currently have a Javascript loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Jinja `for` loop to build the table.

```html
<table id="testcaseTable2" style="width:50%">
  {% for test_case in form.TestCases %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ loop.index + 1 }}</td>
      <td>{{ test_case }}</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"/> &nbsp;</td> 
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```